# Understanding Spark UI

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, cluster-computing

I am fairly new to Spark, and was playing around it a bit yesterday.
I was trying out the JavaSparkPi example:-

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Computes an approximation to pi
 * Usage: JavaSparkPi [slices]
 */
public final class JavaSparkPi {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaSparkPi").setMaster("local").set("spark.executor.cores", "5");
        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

        int slices = (args.length == 1) ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : 2;
        int n = 100000 * slices;
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            l.add(i);
        }


        JavaRDD<Integer> dataSet = jsc.parallelize(l, slices);

                      while(true) {


            Thread.sleep(10000);

            int count = dataSet.map(new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer call(Integer integer) {
                    double x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
                    double y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
                    return (x * x + y * y < 1) ? 1 : 0;
                }
            }).reduce(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer call(Integer integer, Integer integer2) {
                    return integer + integer2;
                }
            });

            System.out.println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / n);

        }

       // jsc.stop();

    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the Spark UI :-

[image: Screesshot]

I wanted to understand a few things around the same:-

1. Even though I specified number of cores as 5, the UI is showing as 1 throughout the execution. (I am running this on mac, is it some mac restriction).
2. What is meant by the number of RDD blocks in the UI. It goes upto 5 at most, then comes back to 3, then again 5 and so on. Is it some GC going alongside that's happening? When the process starts, the RDD blocks starts from 1, but I have configured slices to be equal to 2, so should it not be 2? Looks like I am missing out something obvious here.

Any help on the above queries will be greatly helpful.

**UPDATE**:-

Upon reading the link :- (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html), I changed local to local[4], which lead to 4 cores being used. Looking further for the second point above.

Comment: Your screenshot's link is missing, not need to delete it, just leave it there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Added the missing link.